# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am storing some values that I am getting from server in the database but when i insert values into database It gives me following exception:

```
   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range
```

I am using the following code for it:

```
       private static final String INSERT = "insert into " 
         + DATABASE_TABLE + "(type,width,height,encoding,data,iid)"+" values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";


     public WineDatabaseAdapter(Context context) {
          this.context = context;
       WineDatabaseHelper openHelper = new WineDatabaseHelper(context);
       this.db=openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
      this.insertStmt=this.db.compileStatement(INSERT);
       }


public long insert(String KEY_TYPE ,String KEY_WIDTH,String KEY_HEIGHT, String KEY_ENCODING,String KEY_DATA,String KeyIId){
           this.insertStmt.bindString(0, KEY_TYPE);
           this.insertStmt.bindString(1, KEY_WIDTH);
           this.insertStmt.bindString(2, KEY_HEIGHT);
           this.insertStmt.bindString(3, KEY_ENCODING);
           this.insertStmt.bindString(4, KEY_DATA);
           this.insertStmt.bindString(5, KeyIId);
           return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
       }
```

and I am inserting values in other class :

```
    db = new WineDatabaseAdapter(HomePageWithPhoneIsOfflineDialog.this);
  db.insert( type,width, height,encoding, data1,iid);
```

and following is the stacktrace:

```
         11-03 17:32:15.406: WARN/System.err(22895): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x319db0
        11-03 17:32:15.406: WARN/System.err(22895):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.native_bind_string(Native Method)
        11-03 17:32:15.406: WARN/System.err(22895):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:244)
        11-03 17:32:15.406: WARN/System.err(22895):     at com.emx.Winwcountry.database.WineDatabaseAdapter.insert(WineDatabaseAdapter.java:52)
        11-03 17:32:15.406: WARN/System.err(22895):     at com.emx.Winwcountry.HomePageWithPhoneIsOfflineDialog$1.onClick(HomePageWithPhoneIsOfflineDialog.java:144)
       11-03 17:32:15.406: WARN/System.err(22895):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
         11-03 17:32:15.406: WARN/System.err(22895):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        11-03 17:32:15.406: WARN/System.err(22895):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
      11-03 17:32:15.406: WARN/System.err(22895):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
         11-03 17:32:15.406: WARN/System.err(22895):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       11-03 17:32:15.406: WARN/System.err(22895):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
       11-03 17:32:15.406: WARN/System.err(22895):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
          11-03 17:32:15.406: WARN/System.err(22895):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
         11-03 17:32:15.406: WARN/System.err(22895):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it is pretty straight forward. Just read the error.

> > bind or column index out of range

You have 6 ? in your string :

```
 private static final String INSERT = "insert into " 
     + DATABASE_TABLE + "(type,width,height,encoding,data,iid)"+" values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

and you are trying to bind a column with index 7 here :

```
this.insertStmt.bindString(7, KeyIId);
```

**Edit:** 
The index used by bindString is 1-based, so you have to start your index from 1.

Comment: I have corrected that also instead it is giving the same exception

Comment: can you post the code where you have initialised `insertStmt`

Comment: Your code looks fine. Could you post the stacktrace. Maybe we could find something there.

Comment: Please make sure that the `type,width,height,encoding,data,iid` columns are present in the table you are querying.

Comment: Also make sure that you are not passing any `null` values when you are binding the parameters.

Comment: Yes these columns are present in the table and the values are not null

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4692/discussion-between-ekjyot-and-aki)

Answer (score 0):

see you have mentioned 6 columns but you are setting 7 columns inside your insert() function.Also start the index from 0 not from 1.So your index will range from 0 to 5.

Comment: I changed the code acc to you but it is still giving same exception

Comment: @ekjyot.All datatypes correct according to table's column datatype?.Please check.